# Sqoop unable to import data from MYSQL to HBASE

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

Hi I am new in bigdata and I am trying to import data from `mysql` to `hbase` using sqoop.

```
sqoop import –connect jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:3306/FBI_DB –table FBI_CRIME –hbase-table H_FBI_CRIME –column-family cd –hbase-row-key ID –m 1 –username root -P
```

> ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: No columns
>   to generate for ClassWriter.

Once I had used `––driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` but still didn’t get success.

Please help, What is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to specify the names of the columns that you want to import, like this:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:3306/FBI_DB \
--table FBI_CRIME \
--hbase-table H_FBI_CRIME \
--columns "columnA,columnB" \
--column-family cd \
--hbase-row-key ID \
-m 1 \
--username root -P
```